# How to get CPU usage on a multi core system

Tags: linux, node.js, cpu-usage, htop

How to know the CPU usage in percentage on multi core system. I tried the below sample code using os npm but it does not return the result what I am actually looking into it. I am expecting the result something similar to linux top command. Any help on this will be helpful.

```
setInterval(function() {

    os.cpuUsage(function(v){
        console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + v );
    });

}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Package [`os-utils`](https://github.com/oscmejia/os-utils) is only an API to get some data from the system, you should build your interface using it to obtain something like a top command in Linux.

Instead if you want something ready to be used you can take a look at [`vtop`](https://github.com/MrRio/vtop) package that does exactly what you need.

```
sudo npm install -g vtop

vtop
```

Comment: You can also use Windows status APIs (on any PC) as well as PMU events (x86 CPUs but similar on others). All this is well documented. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to dig it out. If I find the time, I'll post.